# Why doesn't React use the object reference as key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

When rendering a list of items, React uses the index of each item as a default key, if none is supplied.

```js
return <div>
    {this.props.shows.map(show => <ShowComp title = {show.title}/>)}
</div>;
```

But why doesn't React use the **JS object reference** of each item instead? Seems to me like a much safer option, as it would not cause re-rendering of any of the items if the list order changes (as opposed to the index approach).

I'm relatively new to React, so I'm sure there's an underlying reason.

In Angular, `ngFor` (which renders a list of elements, similar to mapping object to React elements), it also has a `trackBy` configuration option (which is the equivalent of `key` in React). However, if it's not supplied, it uses the object references as an identifier, which seems more natural.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not using the reference of the object by default is all React's developpers choice.

Keep in mind it doesn't have to be unique across all the items, it has to be unique across the siblings of each item.

As shown here : https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

You could definitely use a not so unique key that's only unique across siblings.

Also, is using the reference of the object faster than most small integer found in unique ids ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I got the "unique across siblings part", but I still don't see why I can't use the object reference as the key, and why I have to use a string or a number. Object references are inheritently unique for each object. Maybe I'm just asking the wrong question?